Multiple retry spec mutually resets each other. How to avoid this?
I'm using Spring WebClient with ExchangeFilterFunction which adds retry logic to all webclient instances.
public ExchangeFilterFunction filterFunction() {
    return (req, next) -> next.exchange(req)
        .flatmap(response -> Mono.just(response)
            .filter(it -> it.statusCode().isError())
            .flatmap(it -> it.createException())
            .flatmap(Mono::error)
            .thenReturn(response))
        .retryWhen(
            Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .filter(th -> !(th instance of WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests))
         )
        .retryWhen(
            Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1000))
                .filter(th instance of WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests)
        )
}

I'm facing the problem with two different retry specifications which can mutually reset each other. filter(..) method resets retry counter for each specification. In theory, endless query attempts are possible, if we facing responses something like that:
500 -> 429 -> 500 -> 429 -> 500 -> 429...
I want at most 6 retry with 3 from each spec or maybe 3 retries at all (For 429 and 5xx together). How i can deal with it?
I've tried to create custom retry specification which keeps general counter for both response types. Maybe there are other solutions?
